# Passing command line arguments to WPF Core 3.0 sideloaded application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, uwp

I have a WPF app that runs on Core 3.0. I published it via Windows Application Packaging Project. Because it's WPF app, I needed to add this to appxmanifest:

```
<Extensions>
  <uap5:Extension
    Category="windows.appExecutionAlias"
    Executable="MyApp.exe"
    EntryPoint="MyApp">
    <uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
      <uap5:ExecutionAlias Alias="MyApp.exe" />
    </uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
  </uap5:Extension>
</Extensions>
```

Then I published the WPF app as sideloaded and it works just fine when I start it from the Windows Start menu. The problem is that I need to start it from command line and I need to pass few command line arguments. But, when I start the app from command line by typing the alias, it only passes this argument:
-ServerName:App.App7adfdfg54shnsdfh87asrgsdfg1.mca
which is not my argument - mine arguments are not passed at all. So then I tried to add this to my WPF .csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract">
  <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.18362.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\8.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd</HintPath>
  <IsWinMDFile>true</IsWinMDFile>
</Reference>
```

so I could call this in my WPF App.xaml.cs file:

```
using test = Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInstance;
...
Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.IActivatedEventArgs args = test.GetActivatedEventArgs();
```

But after doing this, args are null. Any ideas how to solve this and actually pass arguments to my WPF app? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, You cannot pass parameters to the UWP app via the command line (Even WPF application). You might consider using a URI scheme instead of a command line scheme, this is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation)

Comment: Where are you calling `Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInstance.GetActivatedEventArgs()`? Are you running inside the container when it's `null`?

Comment: I'm calling it at the beginning of the OnStartup method in App.xaml.cs file.

Comment: @JiříBatulka: And how do you confirm that it is `null`?

Comment: @mm8 A simple MessageBox after if (args == null) statement.

Comment: @JiříBatulka Hi, is the answer from mm8 is helpful? if so, please mark it as an answer, thank you

Comment: @Richard Zhang - MSFT Hi, I had to switch my priority somewhere else, I'll do it as soon as I'll try the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing few lines in the .appxmanifestlines file.
Add he reference:

```
xmlns:uap5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5"
```

Add it to the IgnorableNamespaces:

```
IgnorableNamespaces="uap uap5 rescap desktop4">
```

And add this to AppExecutionAlias:

```
<uap5:AppExecutionAlias desktop4:Subsystem="console">
     <uap5:ExecutionAlias Alias="DeploymentScripts.UI.exe" />
</uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
```

Then it's possible to access arguments even from `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`